# + operator inside a string doing addition in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, concatenation

I have a line of code that logs to file.

```
getLogger.Debug("Smaggeggy is Yes + descendantNodes count " & usaaFolderNode.GetDescendantNodes(1).Count.ToString())
```

This line is throwing an exception...

```
Conversion from string "Smaggeggy is Yes " to type 'Double' is not valid.
```

Which mean thats there is some kind of casting exception.  Which is telling me that it is trying to add.  Now I that putting quotes around a string is making it a string literal?
Why would putting a + sign inside that string throw an exception?

Comment: Please provide the source for the Debug method. It is more likely the code in that method is causing this error.

Comment: What is the expected result here? Is descendantNodes  some kind of parameter?

Comment: If this is Log4Net then it looks like your appender is not configured correctly

Comment: It is log4net, could you please expand on your comment of configured incorrectly...